# Original error: unknown error: unable to discover open pages

Tags: android, python, webview, appium

When i test apps with appium,and switch to WebView context.There is an error occurred.
logs:
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTUA4.png)
android:7.1.2,
webview:52.0.2743.100

Comment: Did you added: WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

Comment: Yes,but it's useless.I can debug it with Chrome,and i can get WebView handle,but can't switch to it.

Answer (score 0):

There can be following checks you can do for the problem you stated.

1. Below command should return device in online mode.

   ```
     adb devices
   ```
2. You have to make sure the `chromedriver.exe` in your `appium` bundle should be latest. If not download from here - https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.9/
3. Check if you are able to view the app webview screen here - chrome://inspect/#devices

Comment: I did those yet,but when i run my code,the error was occured.

Comment: @BcTang - Are you sure your device is online ? Can you show adb devices output and also you have to share appium full logs.

Comment: Yes.    `C:\Users\tang>adb devices
List of devices attached
127.0.0.1:21513 device`

Comment: My code can run and open the application, but it just fails when switching to the WebView context.

Comment: @BcTang r u using a device using wifi connection?

Comment: I use The simulator

Comment: @BcTang - have u given this name to the emulator "127.0.0.1:21513" u created usually the name is like emulator-5554. Please confirm I believe your emulator is not started correctly ? 
Also simulator is used with iOS environment and it has nothing related to android, for android the device name is Emulator.

Comment: I just run this emulator for Android,and i' sure this emulator is started correctly.Because there are some person use it normality.

Comment: @BcTang - Did u manually run it before you run your script to make sure its available ?

Comment: Of course.It can run manually and run some script except switch to WebView.

Comment: As far as logs are concerned it shows error is coming because chrome driver version may not support chrome browser / webview version present in emulator, so try updating chromedriver.exe at path => C:/Users/tang/AppData/Roaming/npm/noode_modules/appium/node_modules/_appium-chromedriver@4.10.1@appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/win/chromedriver.exe 
try versions like 2.22,2.23,2.25,2.26
Note- Check path once again in your logs, there may be some typo in path mentioned

Comment: I had solved this problem,it was caused by CrossWalk

Comment: @BcTang - Can you give more details to make us more aware about the issue?

Comment: In CrossWalk App,CrossWalk replace WebView,so can't get pages of WebView with the official chromedriver.You just use a driver that was fixed.[link](https://github.com/piotrekkmt/chromedriver-appium)